# How to Fetch OrderId After checkout in Magento

Tags: magento

Hello I am creating a Observer in Magento to fetch OrderId 
i have created an event name as  in my config.xml
logically this event has to run after checkout 
but in my case this event is running once i clicked on ADD TO CART
here is my config.xml file

```
        <events> 
  <sales_quote_save_after>
             <observers>
                 <salesorder>

                     <class>IlexSquare_SalesOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>salesOrder</method>
                 </salesorder>
             </observers>
  </sales_quote_save_after>
</events>
```

here is My Observer

```
class IlexSquare_SalesOrder_Model_Observer
{
        public function salesOrder($observer)
         {
     die('7878');
    }
}
```

But this die is running whenever i click on Add to Cart .. m missing something.
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying certain solution i got my answer

```
    <events> 
  <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
             <observers>
                 <salesorder>

                     <class>IlexSquare_SalesOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>salesOrder</method>
                 </salesorder>
             </observers>
  </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
</events>
```

just add this section in `<frontend>`tag instead of writing in `<global>` tag.